# How show bootstrap modal on window on load in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

// I found it in jquery but i want it  in javascript is there any alternative code. Please help, thanks

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

      $(window).on('load',function(){
         $('#myModal').modal('show');
      });

 </script>
```

Comment: bootstrap need jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I believe bootstrap toggles a class on the modal (haven't looked it up recently.

The plain JS equivalent would be

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const modal = document.querySelector('#myModal');
  if (modal) {
    modal.classList.add('show');
    modal.style.display = 'block';
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You may need to check the bootstrap docs to be sure what the class name it adds in.

Comment: Just edited my answer. classname was right, but for some reason bootstrap doesn't have the display property set inside the `.show` class, so you have to manually add it